How to use Switch statement in Power Automate?
I'm trying to add a simple switch statement in my Power Automate flow, but it's failing when trying to save.
Here's the minimal example I've created to reproduce the issue:
1.- Create a recurrence trigger, set to 5 minutes interval:

2.- Initialize a test variable as an array for example:

3.- Include an apply to each pointing to the variable we just created:

4.- Add the switch statement pointing to anything, for example the apply to each:

5.- Try to save, it will throw an error "We ran into an error while validating your flow. Please try again."
How can I use a Switch statement to control outputs of the apply to each?

Just after posting the question I've decided to check adding a random case to see if it works and it worked:

So, a case is required, the default case is not enough to save the flow.
